# Is the current drag to launcher behaviour the new default or a bug?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher, drag-and-drop

On Natty, I could drag a file to an icon on the launcher to bring up the window (e.g.: drag an image to the Firefox icon and wait for its window to show and then drop the file on, say, mediafire or Gmail window to upload). Now it just doesn't work anymore.

I've [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/870769) about it but nobody answered. I'm wondering if this is the new default behaviour? If not, please try to reproduce the bug in your systems (I've confirmed it in two computers) and mark the bug as affecting you, please.

Comment: I can drag an image to the Firefox launcher on my system and it works properly (interesting to note that Chrome doesn't work this way, though). At any rate, AskUbuntu is not the proper place to ask questions about known bugs; you should instead "bump" the bug by posting a new comment on it saying you can still replicate that behavior in 11.10.

Comment: As you mean 'Natty' but wrote 'Maverick' in your bug report you maybe should change that.

Comment: This doesn't work in any applications. I asked here because I don't know if it's a bug at all. Maybe it's a new default behaviour and I'm just annoying the developers by asking. But I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: This as been confirmed as a bug in launchpad.